# MySql query error, returning empty set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four tables in my db

```
oc_paypal_cod_order
oc_paypal_cod_order_transaction

oc_paypal_order
oc_paypal_order_transaction
```

Each table has one row. 
My first query giving me 1 row

```
SELECT `ot`.*, 
    (SELECT count(`ot2`.`paypal_order_id`) 
       FROM `oc_paypal_order_transaction` `ot2` 
       WHERE `ot2`.`parent_transaction_id` = `ot`.`transaction_id` ) AS `children`
FROM `oc_paypal_order_transaction` `ot`
WHERE `paypal_order_id` = '1'
```

But my second query returns empty set, whereas it should return 1 row.

```
SELECT `ot`.*, 
    (SELECT count(`ot2`.`paypal_cod_order_id`) 
       FROM `oc_paypal_cod_order_transaction` `ot2` 
       WHERE `ot2`.`parent_transaction_id` = `ot`.`transaction_id` ) AS `children`
FROM `oc_paypal_cod_order_transaction` `ot`
WHERE `paypal_cod_order_id` = '2'
```

Anyone can please help me with this ?

Comment: You have no rows where `paypal_cod_order_id` takes on the value of `2`.

Comment: Are you sure, in your database with this field paypal_cod_order_id have value 2 ???